# What is the best way to deal with needy question askers

Tags: discussion

So there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713705/updating-integers-in-a-list-by-adding-integers-from-another-list-to-them/21713735#21713735) which will be serving as the example.  Though this particular question is a duplicate, it really doesn't matter in the scope of this question.

In the example, I provide a general answer to the question, but OP downvoted my answer (not a big deal) and demanded a specific **but very slightly different** answer in the comments.  I provided this:

```
[a_i + b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b)]
```

and OP wants this:

```
a = [a_i + b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b)]
```

I responded to the comment by saying OP can just take the answer I provided and assign it to something.  I did this in the comment since I was on my phone at the time.  OP responded with "Please provide working code"

So here are the two sides of the issue:

- On one hand, my answer is not *exactly* what OP wanted.
- On the other hand, OP really should be able to figure out how to take my answer and fit it into what he/she wants with *minimal effort*

So sure, maybe I'm being petty in denying OP the answer they're asking for, but I feel justified because question askers mush show minimal effort to have acceptable questions for the site

So, how should I deal with "needy" question askers such as this? Thanks in advance,

Comment: We've just finished a major question on the issue of help-vamps

Comment: See this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221855/what-can-i-do-about-an-exploitative-user

Comment: Move on and don't waste your time. You've given your answer. From that point it's up to him.

Comment: @Adel A very relevant question (possibly a dupe?), thanks for posting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not obligated to answer anything. If you believe the asker comes across as needy and you don't wish to help him any further then you can just leave the answer as it is and step away.

It's what I do as well in these situations: I'm happy to help someone but my time is not unlimited either, nor is my willingness to help people that require everything to be laid out in front of them.

It is up to you to decide where you draw your line. For me I would have helped a bit further in this case. Although the tone comes across as aggressive he only asked for one more extension which would've been a quick answer so it wouldn't have taken me much time to do so.

Comment: Easy enough, I guess I'm just a little unclear as to where the community consensus is as to where to draw the line or if there even is a community consensus

Comment: @wnnmaw: nobody can tell you what to do or not to do; we're here out of our own free will. Nobody is forcing me. I'm not being held captive. please send help

Comment: In your second paragraph you said you wouldn't edit, then in the third you say you would.  Which is it?

Comment: @Servy: second paragraph was referring to this situation in general, the third to this one specific. I've clarified it a little